# How to format JSON string of data to send from WebView to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, android, json, webview

I want to pass multiple values from Android WebView to JavaScript.
The Problem is, that the String i receive in JS is absolutely raw (like control characters showing in plain text).

So my specific problem is that i send the following String from Java:

```
final String chartData = "{ \"data\": 1000, a: 10, b: 30, c: [ 5, 10, 15 ] }";
```

And what i receive is absolutely raw:

```
"{ \"data\": 1000, a: 10, b: 30, c: [ 5, 10, 15 ] }"
```

But i want this (the java-parsed string):

```
{ "data": 1000, a: 10, b: 30, c: [ 5, 10, 15 ] }
```

I dont handle any JSON now, so you can ignore the "syntaxproblem" in the JSON string. I just want to receive the String correctly first. Here is my code so far:

WebViewActivity.java

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    final String chartData = "{ \"data\": 1000, a: 10, b: 30, c: [ 5, 10, 15 ] }";

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:showAlert('message from android')");
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:createChart('"+chartData+"')");
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/report.html");
```

report.html

```
<div id="debugContainer">
    debug
</div>
```

script.js

```
function createChart(lineChartData){
document.getElementById('debugContainer').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(lineChartData, null, 4);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you receive is stringified JSON, you can JSON.parse() it to have it as a regular object or replace escaped characters. Msg sent through http is always a string. You need to either use a string or parse it to json.

Comment: You're right. JSON.stringify() caused that. It was just a display problem. When i display the received JSON-string directly, the string looks like i expect it. So Json.parse() is the right choise like mentioned. Thanks!